# Why list indices must be integers, not tuple?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

I have this simple program:

```
x = {}
x[1,2] = 3
print x
print x[1,2]
```

It works fine. The fist `print` generates `{(1,2):3}` and the second one generates `3`.

But in my "big" program I seems to do the same but get a `list indices must be integers, not tuple` error. What this error message can mean and how I can resolve this problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're getting that error, then you are trying to index a list, and not a dictionary.

A Python list, like `[1, 2, 3]`, must be indexed with integer values. A dictionary, which is what you have in your example, can be indexed by a wider range of different values.

Answer (score 6):

Note that `x={}` defines `x` to be a *dictionary*, not a list (which can have any hashable as a key, and with syntactic sugar that translates `d[key1,key2]` to `d[(key1,key2)]`).

See, however, [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/), which allows multidimensional arrays if that's really what you want.

Answer (score 2):

```
x = {}
```

This creates a dictionary, not a list.

```
x[1,2] = 3
```

assigns the value 3 to the key (1, 2) a tuple.

A list can only be indexed by integers. Maybe you have mixed up the [] und {} using your dict?